# Define DesignWidth and DesignHeight in StaticResource

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I wonder if I can put `mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"` in `StaticResource`, is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The d: attributes are used by the designer and are ignored by the runtime. It makes no sense to put in StaticResource.

The mc:Ignorable relates to markup compatibility and needs to be applied in each document where it's markup root tag/namespace is specified.